# Swiping between views in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to create a WPF application where I have a number of Views and associated  ViewModels, which I can transverse by swiping (Up, Left, Down, Right) between views.

For Instance, I start in the center view, I can swipe up for one view, or down for a different, left, right, etc.

What would be the best way to implement such behavior?

Is it possible to populate a Grid object with a different UserControl in each cell, and then navigate between the cells, only viewing one cell at a time?

Answer (score 0):

There are prorably existing controls that could handle such a behaviour, but it's very easy to implement to start somewhere.

Create a `ContentControl` in XAML, create a 2D array in code behind and fill it with your UserControls (eagerly or lazily) and then when users clicks a button or presses a key, populate that content control with the right user control.